# Building aiortc library (Python) from Yocto

Tags: python, python-3.x, yocto, bitbake, aiortc

I am not sure if this is the rightest place to ask this but I try anyway. I have to integrate the Python [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) library in an embedded system which uses Yocto for building the entire environment.
Because there is no recipe for such library, I've generated one using pipoe following [this](https://blog.emumba.com/how-to-make-python-packages-part-of-yocto-generated-image-6d4af098eebd) tutorial.
Using the command: `pipoe --package aiortc --version 0.9.28 --python python3` I have generated few bb files inside a custom layer such as: python3-aioice_xx.xx.bb, python3-aiortc_xx.xx.bb, python3-cffi_xx.xx.bb and so on (I think those are dependencies).

Now I wanted to compile this recipe to check if everything is sorted with the command: `bitbake python3-aiortc`, it seems to proceed well and to find all the required files until [this](https://pastebin.com/675gV5tw) error occurs and I don't know how to address it. Can someone help me?

I think that some relevant lines are:

> ERROR: python3-aiortc-0.9.28-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure
>
> ERROR: Do not try to fetch `cffi>=1.0.0' for building. Please add its native recipe to DEPENDS.
>
> ERROR: python3-pyee-7.0.1-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure

Have a look to the complete log that I have linked for further info.

===EDIT===

Added the python3-aiortc recipe content.

```
SUMMARY = "An implementation of WebRTC and ORTC"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc"
AUTHOR = "Jeremy LainÃ© <jeremy.laine@m4x.org>"
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=907b5e856b2e6bcd8a3cc8d338a6166f"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/34/d9c8e19b4d5157721a5b77750116c6bb6355f1d85b92e7de491269b9ee51/aiortc-0.9.28.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "50dc651d643b16c95b0e1ad259baeb51"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "4a41122e043a75c93a80dbb6d884b6f7cf27b774ebdef226d819a2c3a997c550"

S = "${WORKDIR}/aiortc-0.9.28"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3-aioice python3-av python3-cffi python3-crc32c python3-cryptography python3-pyee python3-pylibsrtp"

inherit setuptools3
```

Comment: May you also share contents of  python3-pyee-7.0.bb ?

Answer (score 0):

Your recipe depends on other recipes. I am guessing you don't have them.

- If you have them you probably need to add them to IMAGE_INSTALL_append in local.conf
- If you don't have them, you can try to search for them in OpenEmbedded Index, for example:
  https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=cffi

Comment: I have in the generated recipe the following line:
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3-aioice python3-av python3-cffi python3-crc32c python3-cryptography python3-pyee python3-pylibsrtp" which should be the required dependencies. I have tried to compile the whole image without any success with your indication:

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-numpy python3-socketio python3-aioice python3-av python3-cffi python3-crc32c python3-cryptography python3-pyee python3-pylibsrtp python3-aiortc". The same error occurs.

Comment: The error asks you to put cffi in your recipes DEPENDS variable. it should look something like DEPENDS = "python3-aiortc". It's a bit hard to tell for sure without seeing the recipe.

Comment: I have added the python3-aiortc recipe content (auto-generated by pipoe)